# How do you write arrays to an Oracle 10g XE db using iBatis?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, ibatis, mybatis

I have looked for the answer to this high and low but cannot get the answer.

Basically I have an object I am writing to my db using iBatis. This works fine with primitive types like strings, int's etc but one of the attributes of my object is an array of other objects. I would like to be able to persist this and then later call the 'selectById' statement and retrieve the full object including the array.

Here is the code I have so far:

Mapper.xml

```
  <insert id="insertTrade" parameterClass="TradeObject">
insert into TESTTABLE (
  ORDERID,
  MAXPX,
  COMMISSION,
  ACCOUNTGRP )
values (
  #orderID#, #maxPx#, #commission#, #accountGrp#
)
```

accountGrp is my array but its currently throwing an error. The statement works fine without this field.

The java is like so:

```
  public static void insertTrade (Trade obj) throws SQLException {
  logger.debug("inserting trade. Order Id: " + obj.toString());
sqlMapper.insert("insertTrade", obj);
```

}

Thanks for any help in advance!!

Comment: What is the type of the AccountGrp column?

Comment: In java it is an arrayList of Account objects. In the db Im not sure what to set it to. I guess this is part of my problem. Currently its just set to varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done with Mybatis3, should be similar in the old iBatis stuff.  To get the JDBC stuff, read [this thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3696816290928).  It's a huge thread, but it is there.  Look for "ArrayDescriptor".

Basicually, you need to write a TypeHandler.  In the TypeHandler, call setArray.  Should be something like this in mybatis 3.x.  Your working with a List, just convert with the toArray method.  This is an example, where the parameter is a String[].

```
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;   
.....
public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Object parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException
{
 //null check?

   ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("STRARRAY ", ps.getConnection());
   ARRAY oracleArray = new ARRAY(desc, ps.getConnection(), parameter);
   ps.setArray(i, oracleArray);
}
```

and maybe something like this in ibatis,

```
public void setParameter(ParameterSetter setter, Object parameter) throws SQLException
{
    ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("STRARRAY", setter.getPreparedStatement().getConnection());
    ARRAY oracleArray = new ARRAY(desc, setter.getPreparedStatement().getConnection(), parameter);
    setter.setArray(oracleArray);
}
```

Make your you've built a type, like it says in that thread.

i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STRARRAY AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (255)
```

Then in the SQL map, make sure to reference the type handler.