# How to pass Arraylist of Objects to a Procedure using spring mybatis

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, plsql, mybatis

I want to pass an Arraylist of Objects for e.g.

```
Arraylist <SomeObject> listOFSomeObject
```

Where **SomeObject** is having two attributes **key** and **value**.

On DB side i have a table type of variable i.e.

```
create or replace type tableTypeVariable is table of SomeType;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SomeTypeAS OBJECT
(key VARCHAR2(50),value VARCHAR2(50))
```

Now i want to map my each object of type **SomeObject** from a **listOFSomeObject** to the  **tableTypeVariable**.

Can any body help me with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your ArrayList to an Array using toArray(), and pass it in as described here, [How do you write arrays to an Oracle 10g XE db using iBatis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779584/how-do-you-write-arrays-to-an-oracle-10g-xe-db-using-ibatis)

Answer (score 0):

Note that this a partial answer, it has nothing to do with mybatis. It could well be the case that mybatis won't support this and you'll have to fall back to plain JDBC. In this case this answer may be useful for you.

As far as I remember you cannot do this with plain JDBC, you'll need to use the Oracle driver.
For the custom type refer to this:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/java.101/b10979/oraoot.htm#g1104293

For passing collections, refer to this:
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:3714089787721267::::P11_QUESTION_ID:712625135727

Comment: You can accomplish this with mybatis. Good links for Oracle references.