# MyBatis 3.x trying to read a collection and populate the objects

Tags: oracle11g, mybatis

I'm new to MyBatis and my project requires me to read the data from the Oracle database, populate the objects, reset the data if necessary and insert it back into the database.

I'm trying to read data of a nested table. The nested table column consists of a collection of Oracle defined Custom Objects. To be more specific each record in the table is associated to a collection of Custom Object and the Custom Object consists of three fields namely `nickname`, `date of birth` and `address`.

I'm actually getting an `oracle.sql.ARRAY` data type when trying to retrieve the data. The problem I have here is that I'm not able to map this `oracle.sql.ARRAY` which is being fetched by the JDBC through MyBatis to my objects. All I'm able to do is get the ARRAY cast it to an object array and then to a Struct and iterate through the attributes to get the values.

I can always hand build the beans, but I know its not an efficient way of doing it. I want to configure my result map in a way that it populates my objects. But, I have not been able to do that so far. If anyone has any advice regarding this issue please help me out.

Comment: AngerClown answered it well, use type handler.  See this question for writing arrays.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779584/how-do-you-write-arrays-to-an-oracle-10g-xe-db-using-ibatis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get this to work with a custom `TypeHandler`.

In your ResultMap, do something like this:

```
<result property="arrayOne" column="array[1]" typeHandler="customArrayHandler" />
<result property="arrayTwo" column="array[2]" typeHandler="customArrayHandler" />
```

Then in your `CustomArrayHandler.getResult()` implementation, you can parse the real column name and index out. Then retrieve the array from the ResultSet and get the needed value from the index.

Answer (score 1):

That would require a lot of Oracle specific code in Mybatis and I know they have tried to avoid RDMS specific code in general. I would write your own data mappers to map the arrays to whatever model objects you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot of replying. I did play around with the resultMap, but to no avail. If anyone else came across the same problem, please let me know if you have any advice for me.